# how to extract function definition from c source file

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, cpan

I am working on a perl script that prints out the entire function onto std out given the source file name and function name.
using a regex might not be feasible as i have multiline function prototypes.
any suggestion on whether there are c parser perl modules which might be helpful here.
logic on how can i handle nesting {}.
help me out

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/) SO is not a write-some-code-for-me site. You'll have to try for yourself and when you're stuck somewhere then state your problem here and you'll get help.

Comment: I'll just leave a link to the [Clang module](http://search.cpan.org/~alexbio/Clang-0.06/lib/Clang.pm) on CPAN here.

Comment: Why not just use Cscope?

Answer (score 4):

[MarpaX::Languages::C::AST](https://metacpan.org/release/MarpaX-Languages-C-AST), powered by [Marpa general BNF parser](http://savage.net.au/Marpa.html), parses a C file and gives you an AST with callbacks using which you can extract the function body/definition.